# How can I select the year in react-native-calendars?

Tags: react-native

I am creating a calendar component and using react-native-calendars for it. The problem is that by default I cannot choose the year and I have to move between the months little by little.

```
import { theme } from "@/Common/theme"
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Modal, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native"
import { Calendar as NativeCalendar } from "react-native-calendars"
import ModalSelector from "react-native-modal-selector"
import { useCalendar } from "./useCalendar"

export interface CalendarProps {
    visible: boolean
    onClose: () => void
    onChange: (value: string) => void
    value?: string
}

export const Calendar = (props: CalendarProps): JSX.Element => {
    const { visible, styles, onClose, markedDate, onMarkedDateChange, rest } =
        useCalendar(props)
    const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState("")
    const [currentYear, setCurrentYear] = useState(
        new Date().getFullYear().toString()
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentYear(prevYear => {
            return prevYear
        })
    }, [currentYear])

    const renderYearSelector = () => {
        const years = Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, index) => {
            const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
            return { label: `${currentYear - index}`, key: index.toString() }
        })

        return (
            <ModalSelector
                data={years}
                initValue="Seleccione el año"
                onChange={option => {
                    setSelectedYear(option.label)
                    setCurrentYear(option.label)
                }}
            />
        )
    }

    return (
        <Modal visible={visible} animationType="fade" transparent {...rest}>
            <View style={styles.viewCalendar}>
                <View style={styles.calendarContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.calendarHeader}>
                        <Text style={{ color: theme.colors.WHITE }}>
                            Seleccionar fecha
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.selectDate}>
                            {markedDate && markedDate !== ""
                                ? new Date(markedDate).toLocaleDateString(
                                      "es-CO",
                                      {
                                          day: "2-digit",
                                          weekday: "short",
                                          month: "short",
                                      }
                                  )
                                : new Date().toLocaleDateString("es-CO", {
                                      day: "2-digit",
                                      weekday: "short",
                                      month: "short",
                                  })}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    {renderYearSelector()}
                    <NativeCalendar
                        theme={{
                            calendarBackground: "transparent",
                        }}
                        onDayPress={(date: { dateString: string }) =>
                            onMarkedDateChange(date.dateString)
                        }
                        markedDates={{
                            [markedDate]: {
                                selected: true,
                                color: theme.colors.SECONDARY,
                            },
                        }}
                        current={`${currentYear}-01-01`}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.buttonscontainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onClose}>
                            <Text style={styles.cancel}>CANCELAR</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onClose}>
                            <Text style={styles.accept}>ACEPTAR</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

I tried to use a Modal Selector for it, but only the year is reflected when I deselect the calendar and open it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to select the year in `react-native-calendars.` One way is to use the `onMonthChange` prop. This prop takes a function that will be called when the month changes. In the function, you can get the current year using the `getFullYear()` method. Then, you can use the `setYear()` method to set the year to the desired value.

Another way to select the year is to use the `onYearChange` prop. This prop takes a function that will be called when the year changes. In the function, you can get the new year using the `getFullYear()` method. Then, you can use the `setDate()` method to set the date to the first day of the new year.

Finally, you can also select the year by using the `year` prop. This prop takes a number that represents the year. When you set this prop, the calendar will be displayed for the specified year.